# Compilation failed for Lighttpd 1.4.26 on Lenny AMD64

Tags: compilation, debian, lighttpd, libtool, lenny

yesterday I tried to compile Lighttpd 1.4.26 + mod_h264 on Debian Lenny ( AMD64 ) but it failed. I got those errors :

```
mail:/usr/src/lighttpd/lighttpd-1.4.26# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/lighttpd/lighttpd-1.4.26'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/lighttpd/lighttpd-1.4.26/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_VERSION_H -DLIBRARY_DIR="\"/usr/local/lib\"" -DSBIN_DIR="\"/usr/local/sbin\"" -I. -I..   -D_REENTRANT -D__EXTENSIONS__  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGE_FILES  -g -O2 -Wall -W -Wshadow -pedantic -std=gnu99 -MT lemon.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/lemon.Tpo -c -o lemon.o lemon.c
mv -f .deps/lemon.Tpo .deps/lemon.Po
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -W -Wshadow -pedantic -std=gnu99   -o lemon lemon.o
../libtool: line 827: X--tag=CC: command not found
../libtool: line 860: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
../libtool: line 827: X--mode=link: command not found
../libtool: line 994: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
../libtool: line 995: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
../libtool: line 2239: X-g: command not found
../libtool: line 2239: X-O2: command not found
../libtool: line 2239: X-Wall: command not found
../libtool: line 2239: X-W: command not found
../libtool: line 2239: X-Wshadow: command not found
../libtool: line 2239: X-pedantic: command not found
../libtool: line 2239: X-std=gnu99: command not found
../libtool: line 2408: Xlemon: command not found
../libtool: line 2413: X: command not found
../libtool: line 2420: Xlemon: command not found
../libtool: line 5193: Xgcc "" "" "" "" "" "" "" -o @OUTPUT@ lemon.o : command not found
../libtool: line 5194: Xgcc "" "" "" "" "" "" "" -o @OUTPUT@ lemon.o : command not found
../libtool: line 5199: X: command not found
../libtool: line 5203: : command not found
rm -f configparser.h
../src/lemon -q ./configparser.y ./lempar.c
make[2]: ../src/lemon: Command not found
make[2]: *** [configparser.c] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/lighttpd/lighttpd-1.4.26/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/lighttpd/lighttpd-1.4.26'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After lot of researches on IRC, Google and Mailing list Libtools seems not really up to date for compiling this. Libtootl 2.2+ is not in the backports for AMD64 on Lenny...
Anyone have an idea about the issue, or a solution ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, these types of errors mean that your `libtool` script was generated using a different version of libtool than currently installed. Try this:

```
make maintainer-clean
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

In any case, the problem is not that you don't have libtool 2.2, because the `autogen.sh` script claims only to work with 1.5, and `configure.ac` uses 1.5-style libtool calls.

Comment: Yes, it was close. I found another similar solution ( moved Libtool and created a symlink from /usr/bin ) . But thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you've already done the "autogen.sh" thing (which is the most likely fix) then post the parameters you are giving to "./configure" as it's possible one of those is causing the problems you are seeing (e.g. an attempt to add a feature that requires a dependency that the lighttpd build system doesn't handle correctly on your system).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem while trying to install lighttpd with the H264 Streaming Module.  The solution that ended up working for me was changing the ./configure line to remove --prefix.

```
make maintainer-clean
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-maintainer-mode
make
make install
```